# Modal dialog open default once in website

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I wan't to add modal dialog as information box for how to use website. I have done code, it works, but my problem is that, I have multiple tabs in my browser, and my modal dialog is in default tab. When I change tabs and again come back to the default tab, the modal dialog is shown again. I want to show modal dialog only once when opening website.

```
 <body onload="mumbai();">

       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span><img style="height:20px;width:20px;"src="http://cdn.9appsdownloading.com/group1/M01/35/1C/poYBAFcpqU-AFa5CAAAMm35WLrc217.png"></span><h3 style="display:inline;color:white">Urban Growth of Indian Cities</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="#">Mumbai</a></li>
                       <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="master1.html">Delhi</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="Bengaluru.html">Bengaluru</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="Chennai.html">Chennai</a></li>
                       <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="Kolkata.html">Kolkata</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="Hyderabad.html">Hyderabad</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="modal fade" id="memberModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                     <!--<h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Thank you for signing in!</h4>-->

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="images/Webmap_info_25_8_2017.png"></img>
                </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#memberModal').modal('show');
});

    </script>
```

Comment: Do you reload your site if you click on a tab or do you just change the content?

Comment: All the pages are separate,all are linked with each other.when click on tab new page get opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) to identify that the user just visited your first site:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstSite = sessionStorage['firstSite'];
    if (!firstSite) { // or firstSite != "visited"

        // some code here if the user is new to the site
        $('#memberModal').modal('show');

        sessionStorage['firstSite'] = "visited";
    }
});
```

> **sessionStorage** maintains a separate storage area for each given origin
>   that's available for the duration of the page session (as long as the
>   browser is open, including page reloads and restores)

---

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L23hzsjq/) to show how it works.

Comment: For these line  var firstSite = sessionStorage['firstSite']; gives error:unexpected identifier.

Comment: @SeemaBarate I've added a link to jsFiddle to show you it works

Comment: Thanks Patrick,yesterday solved error and i posted final answer.

Comment: Why bother with sessions when you can just set a local var?

Comment: @ProEvilz Because he reloads his site.

Comment: @PatrickMlr "When I change tabs and again come back to the default tab"

Comment: @ProEvilz And this isn't a reload?

Comment: @PatrickMlr No, switching tabs means switching tabs. Reloading pages means reloading pages. If you feel switching tabs means reloading then what would you say to indicate switching between tabs?

Comment: @ProEvilz You really should read the *whole question* with all of his *comments*.

Comment: @PatrickMlr I have - OP doesn't mention page reloading, only switching between tabs. "I have multiple tabs in my browser, and my modal dialog is in default tab (TAB 1). When I change tabs (TAB 2) and again come back to the default tab (TAB 1), the modal dialog is shown again."

Comment: @PatrickMlr What kind of comment is that? Let's just leave it here. Tell you what, next time someone says switch to a different tab I'll translate that to 'reload the page'. Sigh..

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var yetVisited =sessionStorage['visited'];
    if (!yetVisited) {
        $("#Modal").modal("show").on("shown", function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $("#Modal").modal("hide");
            }, 20000);
        });

        // open popup
       sessionStorage['visited'] ="yes";
    }
    });
```

Thanks Patrick and ProEvilz.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
var visited = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (visited == false) {
    $('#memberModal').modal('show');
    visited = true;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: oh,sorry i am new to this development and its my first website.Thanks for suggestions .